# How to aggregate records when they are equal or "close" respect to multiple columns (time, continuous, categorical)?

Tags: sql, time-series, amazon-redshift

## Context

I'm trying to predict the change in the number of photos taken of beach B<sub>i</sub> (with 1<=i<=N with N the number of beaches) given the sea level and some features specific to B<sub>i</sub>.

The sea level changes through time which is indicated in the database by two timestamps: start_datetime and end_datetime. It can change for 10+ reasons (source_id) that I want to take in account, including:

- SENSOR: The sensor sending a new measurement (can be at relatively random as long as there is a change in sea level);
- BOAT: A boat just got close to the sensor, increasing the level.

I would like to avoid having 200 consecutive records for the same sea level, because when I inner join to the table containing the photos taken (in order to not have 600M+ records for intervals where I don't have any photos taken), a lot of those short records are dropped whereas if they were aggregated, they would span longer intervals and for most of them match photos taken and therefore not be dropped.

## Where I am at

- I thought about using the STDDEV window function but I don't know how to choose a relevant dynamic window size.
- I thought about computing the incremental change between each adjacent records but I don't want to aggregate records that go from 0 to 1000 by step of 0.1.

## Examples

#### CASE 1: SAME SOURCE_ID, CONTINUOUS IN TIME, TINY CHANGES IN SEA LEVEL

I would like to aggregate small changes (+- 1% max) relative to the first sea level value (here 1732), adjacents in time ({start_time of the i<sup>th</sup> row} = {end_datetime of the i-1<sup>th</sup> row} +-2seconds), and from the same source_id. Going from this:

```
| start_datetime | end_datetime  | sea_level | source_id |
|----------------|---------------|-----------|-----------|
| 4/30/19 20:15  | 4/30/19 21:36 | 1731      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 19:52  | 4/30/19 20:15 | 1734      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 19:29  | 4/30/19 19:52 | 1731      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 19:20  | 4/30/19 19:29 | 1732      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 18:32  | 4/30/19 19:20 | 1734      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 18:22  | 4/30/19 18:32 | 1732      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 18:04  | 4/30/19 18:22 | 1734      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 17:49  | 4/30/19 18:04 | 1731      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 17:31  | 4/30/19 17:49 | 1734      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 17:22  | 4/30/19 17:31 | 1732      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 16:53  | 4/30/19 17:22 | 1734      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 16:39  | 4/30/19 16:53 | 1731      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 16:16  | 4/30/19 16:39 | 1734      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 16:09  | 4/30/19 16:16 | 1731      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 15:24  | 4/30/19 16:09 | 1734      | SENSOR    |
| 4/30/19 15:07  | 4/30/19 15:24 | 1732      | SENSOR    | 1st value
```

to be aggregated into this:

```
| start_datetime | end_datetime  | sea_level | source_id |
|----------------|---------------|-----------|-----------|
| 4/30/19 15:07  | 4/30/19 21:36 | 1732      | SENSOR    | 1732 = AVG(AGG RECORDS)
```

#### CASE 2: CHANGE OF SOURCE_ID

If there is a different source_id, independently of the change in sea level, I want to keep this difference, going from this:

```
| start_datetime| end_datetime  | sea_level | source_id |
|---------------|---------------|-----------|-----------|
| 4/20/19 7:26  | 4/20/19 7:32  | 1732      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 7:19  | 4/20/19 7:26  | 1734      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 7:10  | 4/20/19 7:19  | 1731      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 6:47  | 4/20/19 7:10  | 1732      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 6:11  | 4/20/19 6:47  | 1731      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 5:54  | 4/20/19 6:11  | 1732      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 5:49  | 4/20/19 5:54  | 1734      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 5:37  | 4/20/19 5:49  | 1732      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 5:23  | 4/20/19 5:37  | 1731      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 5:04  | 4/20/19 5:23  | 1734      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/19/19 23:22 | 4/20/19 5:04  | 1968      | BOAT      | ***
| 4/19/19 23:05 | 4/19/19 23:22 | 1731      | SENSOR    |o
| 4/19/19 23:00 | 4/19/19 23:05 | 1732      | SENSOR    |o
| 4/19/19 22:49 | 4/19/19 23:00 | 1734      | SENSOR    |o
| 4/19/19 22:38 | 4/19/19 22:49 | 1731      | SENSOR    |o
| 4/19/19 22:32 | 4/19/19 22:38 | 1734      | SENSOR    |o
| 4/19/19 22:25 | 4/19/19 22:32 | 1731      | SENSOR    |o
```

to be aggregated into this:

```
| start_datetime| end_datetime  | sea_level | source_id |
|---------------|---------------|-----------|-----------|
| 4/20/19 5:04  | 4/20/19 7:32  | 1734      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/19/19 23:22 | 4/20/19 5:04  | 1968      | BOAT      | ***
| 4/19/19 22:25 | 4/19/19 23:22 | 1733      | SENSOR    |o
```

#### CASE 3: SAME SOURCE_ID BUT BIG CHANGE

If the reason for the change is the same but one (or more) of the changes exceed a +-1% change, I don't want it to be aggregated with the other records, such that this:

```
| start_datetime | end_datetime  | sea_level | source_id |
|----------------|---------------|-----------|-----------|
| 4/20/19 12:23  | 4/20/19 12:37 | 1731      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 12:10  | 4/20/19 12:23 | 1732      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 11:49  | 4/20/19 12:10 | 1734      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 11:43  | 4/20/19 11:49 | 1731      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 11:36  | 4/20/19 11:43 | 1734      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 11:31  | 4/20/19 11:36 | 1732      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 11:25  | 4/20/19 11:31 | 1910      | SENSOR    | ***
| 4/20/19 11:18  | 4/20/19 11:25 | 1911      | SENSOR    | ***
| 4/20/19 11:11  | 4/20/19 11:18 | 1910      | SENSOR    | ***
| 4/20/19 11:03  | 4/20/19 11:11 | 1912      | SENSOR    | ***
| 4/20/19 10:55  | 4/20/19 11:03 | 1732      | SENSOR    |o
| 4/20/19 10:49  | 4/20/19 10:55 | 1731      | SENSOR    |o
| 4/20/19 10:35  | 4/20/19 10:49 | 1734      | SENSOR    |o
| 4/20/19 10:27  | 4/20/19 10:35 | 1731      | SENSOR    |o
| 4/20/19 10:19  | 4/20/19 10:27 | 1734      | SENSOR    |o
```

becomes this:

```
| start_datetime | end_datetime  | sea_level | source_id |
|----------------|---------------|-----------|-----------|
| 4/20/19 11:31  | 4/20/19 12:37 | 1732      | SENSOR    |°
| 4/20/19 11:03  | 4/20/19 11:31 | 1911      | SENSOR    | ***
| 4/20/19 10:19  | 4/20/19 11:03 | 1733      | SENSOR    |o
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, doing exactly what you want is not feasible in SQL.  The problem is when there are gradual changes that exceed 1%.  That is, a sequence of values such as:

- 1732
- 1742
- 1752
- 1762

No gap is 1%, but the overall difference based on the first value is 1%.  You cannot readily tell where a new group is going to start without going through all the previous data.

Some databases support recursive CTEs, which allow the logic to be in the database.  Redshift is not one of them.  And, recursive CTEs are essentially just a somewhat more efficient RBAR calculation (row-by-agonizing row).

That said, I'm not sure if this is a big deal in your situation (none of your three examples have this).  Let's ignore the *gradual* changes and find periods that change based on:

- Source changes
- A jump of more than 1% between adjacent records

This is doable as a gaps-and-island problem, using `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select min(start_datetime) as start_datetime,
       max(end_datetime) as end_datetime,
       sensor_id,
       avg(sea_level)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when sensor_id <> prev_sensor_id or
                           sea_level < 0.99 * prev_sea_level or
                           sea_level > 1.01 * prev_sea_level
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (order by start_datetime) as grp 
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(sensor_id) over (order by start_datetime) as prev_sensor_id,
                   lag(sea_level) over (order by start_datetime) as prev_sea_level
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp, sensor_id;
```

The innermost subquery gets the previous sensor and sea level information.  This is used to determine where a group starts.  The cumulative sum in the middle subquery assigns a group id based on the cumulative sum of starts up to each record.

Finally, the outer query aggregates the value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon! I think I am going to invalidate my aggregation for (MAX(sea_level) - MIN(sea_level)) / MEAN(sea_level) > +-0.04, and see how many aggregations I'm left with, I have huge amounts of data I prefer to filter out more than I should rather than polluting my predictions.

Answer (score 0):

This looks awefully like WINDOW FUNCTIONS to the rescue. You can find the difference between the previous end date and the next start date like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *, DATEDIFF(SECOND, end_datetime, LEAD(start_datetime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY start_datetime)) [RecordDifference],
LEAD(sea_level,1) OVER (ORDER BY start_datetime) [NextSeaLevel]
FROM <YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE>
```

Once you've done that you can GROUP BY to aggregate:

```
SELECT MIN(start_datetime) [start_datetime], MAX(end_datetime) [end_datetime], [RecordDifference]
FROM
(
    SELECT start_datetime, end_datetime, sea_level, DATEDIFF(SECOND, end_datetime, LEAD(start_datetime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY start_datetime)) [RecordDifference]
    FROM <YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE>
) [rawData]
GROUP BY [RecordDifference]
```

You can read more about window functions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html).

For the record this is SQL Server syntax, but it's fairly similar to RedShift.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time Jim! I think this doesn't fit in my constraint on the 1% change and source_id change...